# H5 accordion to work on Shopify product page using Custom Product Builder App

Tags: javascript, shopify

part of the theme we are using on Shopify has h5 turn product descriptions into accordion.
We had started using the Custom Product Builder App on our store for a couple of products and it picks up the product description direction from the Shopify Products page and shows it in their app. It didnt however let the h5 tag turn content into accordion.

i hired a developer to do it, and he did it, but then we had to switch to a new theme and we lost the customisation. I managed to find the code in the theme.liquid but something is not right - i shows the title and content and svg icons but the accordion does not work.

Here is the page live:
https://wholesalemineralmakeup.com.au/products/custom-eyeshadow-palette

can anyone see what is missing or not correct from the code below:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    
   <script>
var handle1 = setInterval(function(){
$('.cpb-product-description h5').nextUntil("h5").addClass('invalid');
if($('.cpb-product-description h5').length){
$(document).on('click', '.cpb-product-description h5', function(){
    $(this).nextUntil("h5").toggleClass('showElem');
})

$('.cpb-product-description h5').addClass('plus_01');
$(document).on('click', '.cpb-product-description h5', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("minus_01");
})
clearInterval(handle1);
}
},100);
</script> 
<script>
var handle = setInterval(function(){
if($('.cpb-product-description h5').length){
$('.cpb-product-description h5').append('<svg class="plus1" version="1.1" width="20" height="20" id="tab-plus" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M88.3,48.2H52.8V12.8c0-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.8-2.8s-2.8,1.2-2.8,2.8v35.5H11.8C10.2,48.2,9,49.5,9,51s1.2,2.8,2.8,2.8h35.5v35.5c0,1.5,1.2,2.8,2.8,2.8c1.6,0,2.8-1.3,2.8-2.8V53.8h35.5c1.5,0,2.8-1.2,2.8-2.8S89.8,48.2,88.3,48.2z"></path></svg><svg class="minus1" version="1.1" width="20" height="20" id="tab-minus" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve"><g><path d="M88.3,52.8H11.8C10.2,52.8,9,51.5,9,50s1.2-2.8,2.8-2.8h76.5c1.5,0,2.8,1.2,2.8,2.8S89.8,52.8,88.3,52.8z"></path></g></svg>');
clearInterval(handle);
}
},100);
</script>
<script>
 var panels1 = setInterval(function(){if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches) {
 if($('.cpb-product-panel').length){
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cpb-product-panel").prependTo(".cpb-product-title");
  });
 clearInterval(panels1);
}}
 },100);
  
</script>
  <script>
 var panels2 = setInterval(function(){if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches) {
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
   var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   if(scrollTop >= 10) {
   $(".cpb-panels-container").css("padding-top", "0px");
   }
});
  clearInterval(panels2);
 }},100);
    
  </script>

  {% if page.product %}
<div class="cpb-product-description">
  <h5 class="cpb-product-title">Product Description</h5>
  <div class="cpb-product-panel">
    <p>This is the first panel.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cpb-product-panel">
    <p>This is the second panel.</p>
  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}

<style>
.cpb-product-description {
  border: 0px solid black;
  padding: 0px;
}

.cpb-product-title {
  margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.cpb-product-panel {
  display: none;
}

.plus1, .minus1 {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```